# MVC Url not pathing correctly

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-routing, url-routing

I have a link going to

`<a class="k-link" href="/UserView/EditByName?UserName=MVCTest6">Profile</a>`

When the link it is clicked it goes to this

```
URL: http://localhost:3256/MVCTest6/Create
```

which works when i am logged in as an admin user. (The folder has no security in a web.config setting it apart).  This link actually works on another part of the page.

The user also already exist and has been authenticated.

Can this please be explained?

Comment: can you post the controller's part of code ?

Comment: @Athiban... thanks that made me look at the control forgot I had code to redirect if user profile was not already created.

Answer (score 0):

I get it ! This is where the problem is,

```
 return RedirectToAction("Create", User.Identity.Name);
```

you are using this overload `RedirectToAction("Action", "Contoller");`

So the later part is taken as the controller. Try other overloads that matches your requirement, if you are trying to pass values to another action, which must be like

```
 return RedirectToAction("Create", new {UserName = User.Identity.Name});
```

Answer (score -1):

I forgot I had logic in place to redirect if user profile was not created.  This was causing the problem.  My test user didnt have profile already setup so it was redirecting to the create page

```
public ActionResult EditByName(string userName)//EditByName
        {
            if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
            {
                UserModel usermodel = repository.Get(User.Identity.Name);// db.UserModels.Find(id);
                if (usermodel == null)
                {
                    return RedirectToAction("Create", User.Identity.Name);
                }
                return View(usermodel);
            }
            else { return RedirectToAction("Login", controllerName: "AccountView"); }
        }
```

Comment: Edit the question with this part instead of posting as an answer pls

Comment: sorry about that... wont do it again